# Can I add categories to a Kendo grid filterable list?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo grid for my tables, and I want to filter on categories in addition to the actual values.

For example, imagine the column has the integer values 1-10. By default, I can client-side-filter on any of those values, and I want to keep that. However, I want to add the evens, the odds, and the prime numbers to my filter options.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is untested and only a theory but the grid does have a [filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit) event that will allow you to modify the content of the filter dropdown displayed to the user.  You'll be able to add or modify some of the values created by the grid.

The next thing you'll have to do is the override the datasource's [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) function to handle the your special values:

```
grid.dataSource.filter = function() {
    //Apply your odd / even filter logic here using the this keyword
    var result = this.yourfilterLogicHere();

    //Make sure to return the expected format
    return result;
}
```